# Creating a list of Class objects from a file with no duplicates in attributes of the objects

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently taking some computer science courses in school and have come to a dead end and need a little help. Like the title says, I need of create a list of Class objects from a file with objects that have a duplicate not added to the list, I was able to successfully do this with a python `set()` but apparently that isn't allowed for this particular assignment, I have tried various other ways but can't seem to get it working without using a set. I believe the point of this assignment is comparing data structures in python and using the slowest method possible as it also has to be timed. my code using the `set()` will be provided.

```
import time

class Students:
    def __init__(self, LName, FName, ssn, email, age):
        self.LName = LName
        self.FName = FName
        self.ssn = ssn
        self.email = email
        self.age = age

    def getssn(self):
        return self.ssn

def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    f = open('InsertNames.txt', 'r')
    studentlist = []
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        parsed = line.split(' ')
        parsed = [i.strip() for i in parsed]
        if parsed[2] not in seen:
            studentlist.append(Students(parsed[0], parsed[1], parsed[2], parsed[3], parsed[4]))
            seen.add(parsed[2])
        else:
            print(parsed[2], 'already in list, not added')
    f.close()
    print('final list length: ', len(studentlist))
    t2 = time.time()
    print('time = ', t2-t1)
main()
```

A note, that the only duplicates to be checked for are those of the .ssn attribute and the duplicate should not be added to the list. Is there a way to check what is already in the list by that specific attribute before adding it?

**edit:** Forgot to mention only 1 list allowed in memory.

Comment: Consider writing `Students(*parsed)` which has the advantage of implicitly checking the number of fields.  (And name the class `Student` since it's just one.)

Comment: I like the `(*parsed)` technique! thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
if not any(s.ssn==parsed[2] for s in studentlist):
```

without committing to this comparison as the meaning of `==`.  At this level of work, you probably are expected to write out the loop and set a flag yourself rather than use a generator expression.

Comment: Ah, your answer reminded me of a detail I left out, there is only allowed to be 1 list in memory.

Comment: @deadsightsx: Hopefully the list made by `split()` doesn't count!

Comment: I don't think it does otherwise the professor should have mentioned that the first time I showed him the code, thanks for the answer though, it appears to do what is intended as it is painfully slower than the `set()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already took the time to write a class representing a student and since `ssn` is a unique identifier for the instances, consider writing an `__eq__` method for that class.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.ssn == other.ssn
```

This will make your life easier when you want to compare two students, and in your case make a `list` (specifically not a `set`) of students.

Then your code would look something like:

```
with open('InsertNames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        student = Student(*line.strip().split())
        if student not in student_list:
            student_list.append(student)
```

**Explanation**

1. Opening a file with `with` statement makes your code more clean and
   gives it the ability to handle errors and do cleanups correctly. And
   since `'r'` is a default for `open` it doesn't need to be there.
2. You should `strip` the line before splitting it just to handle some
   edge cases but this is not obligatory.
3. `split`'s default argument is `' '` so again it isn't necessary.
   Just to clarify the meaning of this item is that the absence of a parameter make the `split` use whitespaces. It does not mean that a single space character is the default.
4. Creating the student before adding it to the list sounds like too
   much overhead for this simple use but since there is only one
   `__init__` method called it is not that bad. The plus side of this
   is that it makes the code more readable with the `not in` statement.
5. The `in` statement (and also `not in` of course) checks if the
   object is in that list with the `__eq__` method of that object.
   Since you implemented that method it can check the `in` statement
   for your `Student` class instances.

Only if the student doesn't exist in the list, it will be added.

One final thing, there is no creation of a list here other than the return value of `split` and the `student_list` you created.

Comment: `str.split`'s default is [complicated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Comment: IMO that is not complicated at all and in Python _readability counts_. I guess we have different definitions for complicated.

Comment: My point was that your statement of its default (#3) is wrong.  As for "complicated": it certainly makes common cases brief and readable, but it is magic and non-orthogonal, which I think merits the term.

Comment: Noted and edited to clarify. Still i don't think that is complicated.